# How to create RSS feeds from any webpage that does not have a RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

How to create RSS feeds from any webpage that does not have a RSS feed, I have to create RSS Feed of http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211271.html and put that on my wordpress website. How I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code with PHP CURL and own CSS. This is not the RSS feed but scrap your data as you required.

```
<style>.head { display:block; background-color:#FF0000; 
 color:#FFFFFF;}</style>
<?php
$curl = 
curl_init('http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211271.html');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
exit;
}
curl_close($curl);
$regex = '/<table class="StoryengineTable">(.*?)<\/div>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
echo $list[0];
else 
print "Not found"; 
?>
```